# How to add a column to a table that counts the number of times the lines appear?

Tags: list-manipulation, counting, padding

I am at a complete loss at this. I have a table with 2 columns and *n* lines. Some of the lines are repeated. What I want to do is add a new column that counts the number of repetitions of each line. Example

```
a={{1.1, 2.2},{1.1, 2.2}}
```

then I need something that will add a column `{2,2}` to the end of the table, resulting in

```
{{1.1, 2.2, 2},{1.1, 2.2, 2}}
```

Keeping in mind that I don't know in advance how many times a line will appear in the table. If it helps, the same line will always appear in subsequent positions
Thanks

Comment: Ok, but how do I specify that the column to be inserted is the number of times that line is repeated in the table?

Comment: Tally[a] // Map[Flatten]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following. Not very elegant but it should get the job done.

Generate some data for demonstration purposes...

```
SeedRandom[125];
data = Sort@RandomChoice[{1, 2}, {10, 3}]
```

Determine how many replicates there are.

```
reps = Join @@ Replace[Split[data], x_ :> ConstantArray[Length[x], Length[x]], {1}]
```

Join it all back together.

```
Transpose[Join[Transpose[data], {reps}]]

(*{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 
  1}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 
  2, 3}}*)
```

Comment: +1. This seems to be the fastest on my system for large arrays.

Answer (score 8):

`Transpose` and `Count` might be your friend

```
SeedRandom[125];
data = Sort@RandomChoice[{1, 2}, {10, 2}]
counted = Count[data, #] & /@ data
Transpose@Append[Transpose@data, counted]
```

with sample data

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2,
2}, {2, 2}}
```

output is  (TableForm'd for clarity)

```
1   1   2
1   1   2
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
2   1   2
2   1   2
2   2   3
2   2   3
2   2   3
```

**EDIT** Timing-wise, this starts to get increasingly sluggish at ~4,000 records, so the approaches that use `..Array` or `Dispatch` may be preferable.

Answer (score 8):

```
a = {{1.1, 2.2}, {1.1, 2.2}, {x, b}, {c, d}, {x, b}, {1, 2}}

# /. (Rule[First@#, Append @@ #] & /@ Tally[#]) &[a]

(*
{{1.1, 2.2, 2}, {1.1, 2.2, 2}, {x, b, 2}, {c, d, 1}, {x, b, 2}, {1, 2,1}}
*)
```

For huge lists:

```
# /. Dispatch[Rule[First@#, Append @@ #] & /@ Tally[#]] &[a];
```

Will speed things up nicely.

Also quite fast on large lists:

```
Partition[Flatten[Riffle[#, Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Tally[#][[All, {2, 2}]]]], 3] &@a
```

Unlike the above (where order of elements does not matter), this takes advantage of the OP assumptions of same elements appearing in sequence.

Even faster on large arrays:

```
Block[{tmp = ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], t = Tally[#]},
       tmp[[All, 3]] = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ t[[All, {2, 2}]];
       tmp] &[data]
```

Comment: +1 - would be even faster if one could use - somehow - `Join` instead of `Append`.

Comment: These are clever, but in version 7 I'm not seeing the advantage over the more terse method I posted.  e.g. given `data = Join @@ RandomSample@Split@Sort@RandomInteger[500, {1000000, 2}];` both my code and your `Block` method take almost exactly two seconds on my machine.  What kind of data are you using? -- Edit: in a fresh kernel yours is about 8 to 9 percent faster and both take a bit over one second.  Still not worth the additional complexity in this particular test, IMHO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I went for the "some of the lines are repeated" slant. So, using your generator above, with 200 distinct (all lines end up repeated), I see about the same timings, with 500 (most lines end up repeated) I see yours ~20% slower, with 1000 distinct (resulting in ~1/3 of the lines having repeats) yours times ~40% slower, and with 3000 (~5% have repeats) it's ~55% slower. Both are plenty fast (along with *Andy*'s answer. The others seem to blow up time-wise with larger problems), just fiddled with it as an exercise...

Answer (score 7):

Using `Tally` and rules:

```
SeedRandom[125];
data = Sort@RandomChoice[{1, 2}, {10, 2}];
data /. (Tally[data] /. {{a_, b_}, d_} :> ({a, b} -> {a, b, d})) // TableForm
(* Out:
1   1   2
1   1   2
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
2   1   2
2   1   2
2   2   3
2   2   3
2   2   3 *)
```

This is probably not very fast. On the upside it works even if the lines are not consecutive.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another variation:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}};

Join @@ (Append[##] ~ConstantArray~ #2 & @@@ Tally[data])
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 3, 2},
>  {3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}}
> ```

A refactoring of Andy's fast method that a bit shorter and also a little faster on my machine:

```
With[{reps = ConstantArray[#, #] & /@ Length /@ Split[data]},
  Join[data\[Transpose], {Join @@ reps}]\[Transpose]
]
```

And a combination of `Split` and `ArrayPad` that is nearly as fast and shorter:

```
Join @@ (ArrayPad[#, {0, {0, 1}}, Length@#] & /@ Split[data])
```

Answer (score 4):

Variations on @AndyRoss's method (for sorted data):

```
appndCnts = Join @@
            (ConstantArray[Join[First@#, {Length@#}], Length@#] & /@ Split[#]) &;

appndCnts2 = Join @@ 
   (ConstantArray[
                 PadRight[First@#, 1 + Length@First@#, Length@#], Length[#]
                 ] & /@ Split[#]) &;

SeedRandom[125];
data = Sort@RandomChoice[{1, 2}, {10, 3}];

appndCnts@data 
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 2, 1},
    {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, 
    {2, 1, 1, 1},
    {2, 1, 2, 1}, 
    {2, 2, 1, 1}, 
    {2, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 3}}*)

appndCnts[data] == appndCnts2[data]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll just post this here as another option. This uses `Reap` and `Sow`.

```
rule = Dispatch[Reap[Sow[1, data], _, Rule[#1, Length@#2] &][[2]]];

Transpose @ Join[Transpose[data], {data /. rule}]
```

**EDIT**
A relatively fast approach.

```
data = {{1, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}};

Transpose @ Join[Transpose[data], {data /. Dispatch[Rule @@@ Tally[data]]}]
```

> {{1, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {1,
>   3, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}}

Answer (score 3):

Might as well join the fray.

```
list = RandomInteger[10, {100, 3}];
MapThread[Append, {list, list /. Rule @@@ Tally[list]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = Sort @ RandomChoice[{1, 2}, {10, 3}];
```

Using `Splice` (new in 13.1) and `Counts` (new in 10.0)

```
Replace[list, a_ :> {Splice @ a, a /. Counts @ list}, {1}]
```

{{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1,
1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2,
1, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy` and `Repeated`:

```
list = {{3, 2}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 5}, {1, 5}};

f = Append @@@ Function[x, Transpose@{x, Array[Length@x &, Length@x]}]@# &;

Catenate@GroupBy[#, Repeated, f] &@list

(*{{3, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2}, 
   {2, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 3, 2}, 
   {3, 1, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {1, 5, 2}}*)
```

Or using `Counts`:

```
Append @@@ Transpose@{#, # /. Counts[#]} &@list

(*{{3, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2}, 
   {2, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 3, 2}, 
   {3, 1, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {1, 5, 2}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this counts as an independent solution, but here we go

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = Sort@RandomChoice[{1, 2}, {10, 3}];
Transpose[Insert[Transpose[list], list /. Counts[list], -1]]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1,
> 1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2,
> 1, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
lst={{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,2,1},{1,2,1},{2,2,1},
     {2,1,2},{2,1,2},{2,1,2},{2,1,2}}


MapThread[Prepend, {lst, lst/.Counts[lst]}]
```

```
(* {{3,1,1,1},{3,1,1,1},{3,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,2},
    {2,1,2,1},{2,1,2,1},
    {1,2,2,1},
    {4,2,1,2},{4,2,1,2},{4,2,1,2},{4,2,1,2}
   } *)
```